# Error callback not used for chained then() with ssh2-sftp-client in node.js lambda

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, ssh2-sftp

I'm very new to node and lambda, so I'm probably making some dumb mistakes. I've created a node.js aws lambda function which grabs a file from an s3 event. If the file is gzip it decompresses, uploads it to a sftp server, then creates and uploads a sig file to the same sftp server. It works when everything goes well, but it doesn't seem to correctly trigger errors.

The sftp commands are chained using then, so I would expect any error to fail the subsequent thens.  For example, if I turn off my sftp server, the sftp client will generate a timeout error, but lambda never sees the callback error, only success. The log does show the error output to the console, but it appears to use the success callback after following the rest of the .then() items. Is the connection not correctly recorded as a promise?

Sample log:

```
...
Starting SFTP
Connected to sftp, starting sftp put for lastsub2.dat file.
{ Error: Timed out while waiting for handshake
    at Timeout._onTimeout (/var/task/node_modules/ssh2/lib/client.js:687:19)
    at ontimeout (timers.js:386:14)
    at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:250:5)
    at Timer.listOnTimeout (timers.js:214:5) level: 'client-timeout' } 'Error occured during sftp relay.'
END
```

Example code:

```
console.log('Loading function');
const aws = require('aws-sdk');
const s3 = new aws.S3({
    apiVersion: '2006-03-01'
  });
const zlib = require('zlib');
const fs = require("fs");
const connSettings = {
  host: 'xxx',
  port: '22',
  username: 'xxx',
  password: 'xxx'
};

exports.handler = function (event, context, callback) {
  console.log('Received event:', JSON.stringify(event, null, 2));
  console.log('Bucket Name: ' + event.Records[0].s3.bucket.name);
  console.log('Object Key: ' + decodeURIComponent(event.Records[0].s3.object.key.replace(/\+/g, ' ')));
  const bucket = event.Records[0].s3.bucket.name;
  const key = decodeURIComponent(event.Records[0].s3.object.key.replace(/\+/g, ' '));
  const params = {
    Bucket: bucket,
    Key: key,
  };

  s3.getObject(params, (err, data) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
      const message = 'Error getting object ${key} from bucket ${bucket}. Make sure they exist and your bucket is in the same region as this function.';
      console.log(message);
      callback(message);
    } else {
      if (data.ContentType == 'application/x-gzip') {
        console.log('CONTENT TYPE is application/x-gzip');
        var dataStream = s3.getObject(params).createReadStream().pipe(zlib.Unzip());
        console.log('Created unzip datastream');
        console.log('Starting SFTP');
        let Client = require('ssh2-sftp-client');
        let sftp = new Client();
        sftp.connect(connSettings)
        .then(console.log('Connected to sftp, starting sftp put for ' + key.replace('.gz', '.dat') + ' file.'))
        .then(() => {
            console.log('Finished sftp put for ' + key.replace('.gz', '.dat') + ' file.');
            return sftp.put(dataStream, key.replace('.gz', '.dat'), true, 'utf-8');
        }).then(() => {
          var sigFileName = key.replace('.gz', '.sig');
          var sigStream = fs.createWriteStream('/tmp/' + sigFileName);
          sigStream.end();
          console.log('Created ' + sigFileName + ' sig file.');
          var readStream = fs.createReadStream('/tmp/' + sigFileName);
          console.log('Uploaded ' + sigFileName + ' sig file.');
          return sftp.put(readStream, sigFileName, true, 'utf-8');
        }).then(() => {
            console.log('Ended sftp connection.');
            return sftp.end();
        })
        .then(callback(null, 'Success'))
        .catch ((err) => {
          console.log(err, 'Error occured during sftp relay.');
          callback('Error', err);
        });
      } else {
        callback(null, 'Uploaded file not in gzip format, will not be processed.');
      }
    }
  });
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you are having is happening because you are not returning anything from the `then()`s. The result is that each `then()` is executed immediately without waiting for any of the async sftp functions to return because it resolves immediately to undefined.

You didn't mention what sftp library you're using, but assuming it returns a promise, you should be able to simply return those promises from the the `then()`s.

For example:

```
.then(() => {
      console.log('Finished sftp put for ' + key.replace('.gz', '.dat') + ' file.');
      // assumes stfp.put returns a promise, just return it into the chain
      return sftp.put(dataStream, key.replace('.gz', '.dat'), true, 'utf-8');
    })
```

---

**EDIT based on comments:**

You should be able to call the callback from the then()s.  Looking at the log output now in your edit, isn't this almost what you are expecting when there's an error — it jumps to the catch. You are getting the console output, 'Connected to sftp…' because of the way you are calling that then. Instead of:

```
.then(console.log('Connected to sftp, starting sftp put for ' + key.replace('.gz', '.dat') + ' file.'))
```

it should probably be:

```
.then(() => console.log('Connected to sftp, starting sftp put for ' + key.replace('.gz', '.dat') + ' file.'))
```

The way you have it, the console will log before the error returns from sftp.

Comment: Hi Mark, thank you for your assistance. I'm using https://github.com/jyu213/ssh2-sftp-client, which is supposed to return a promise for each item. I updated the code above to return the commands. It changed the log (doesn't seem to execute the following thens), but still returns a success.

Comment: After digging some more, I suspect the core issue is attempting to use callbacks in promises. I think I'll need to rework the code structure.

Comment: @cninsd You should be able to call the callback from then() without issue. It looks like you're output is almost what you are expecting. See edit above…

Comment: Thank you, after playing around with the code further I determined that the errors were not correctly flowing up the chain of thens - perhaps an issue with the library or my understanding. When I added catches between the then statements it correctly caught the different error tests I ran and invoked the callbacks.